# How to make a DateTime on Symfony 4 entity?

Tags: php, symfony, entity

I have an entity called User and I want to make a DateTime field.

My class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=250)
     */
    private $firstName;

     /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=250)
     */
    private $lastName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=250, nullable = true)
     */
    private $userName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=20)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     *@Assert\DateTime()
     */
    private $regData;


    // GETTERS AND SETTERS
}
```

When I run `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff` I get the following error message:

```
[Semantical Error] The annotation "@Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\DateTime" in property App\Entity\User::$regData does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.
```

I don't understand why I am getting this message error. I thought my code was right.
I am following this part of [Symfony 4](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/DateTime.html) documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Assert\DateTime` only apply a constraint on your property: that means when your submit your form, if the data is not something translatable to a date it will be invalid.

You have to use The `ORM\Column(type="datetime")` for doctrine to store it in the database.

Of course, use both to have data persisted and validated

```
  /**
    * @Assert\DateTime()
    * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
    */
   private $regData;
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I just needed to require Validator.
I ran `composer require validator` and then I ran `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff` and it just worked.